# wcf net.tcp binding throwing error The URI prefix is not recognized, http binding works

Tags: wcf, net.tcp

I have a simple wcf service hosted in IIS 7 on my local computer running windows7, with nettcp binding which i am trying to access using winform, but keep getting same error no matter what i try. i can access the service via http though.

At this point i have spent my whole day trying to figure the reason for this and have gone through most of the post on the topic on stack overflow. At this point i feel i am missing something basic and any feedback from the experts is highly appreciated.

Even if you guide me how to debug this or where to look for the exact cause that would help a lot as i am not seeing anything useful in event log or failed Request tracing :(

steps i have taken

1. set a new website on localhost with net.tcp enabled (without spaces)[image]!
2. made sure all three services for net.tcp are running[image]
3. Disabled security in webconfig (none instead of windows)[image].

my service details

```
namespace WcfService1
{
   public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string Echo(string msg)
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="tcpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:820/Service1.svc"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="tcpBinding" portSharingEnabled="true">
          <security mode="None"></security>
        </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <!--<protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>-->    

    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Full error details

```
The URI prefix is not recognized.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'net.tcp://localhost:820/Service1.svc'.
The requested service, 'net.tcp://localhost:820/Service1.svc' could not be activated. See the server's diagnostic trace logs for more information.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.
```

Comment: Rather doubt this is it, but you can try uncommenting the `<protocolMapping>` section and add `<add binding="netTcpBinding" scheme="net.tcp" />`.  Also look at the IIS logs and the Event Viewer to see if there's any information there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion tim, I had tried that already but goanna look into iis logs and see if i find a nything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the reference through References --> Service Reference? I used your web configuration file and was able to successfully run and consume the WCF Service for a console application.

Comment: Hello Aditya, i am adding it as service reference. Let me ask you this, are you hosting the service locally in IIS or its a part of your solution?

Comment: do you have the service as library or application? i have the service as wcf service application and not library

Comment: I have it as an application and I hosted it locally in IIS.